# Heroku is serving old assets for Rails 5 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I've deployed a new version of a Rails 5 app on Heroku, running on cedar-14 stack. It didn't precompile while deploying, so I did `heroku run rake assets:precompile` manually. Still, I can see it includes old assets while requiring `css` and `js` files.

My files are in `app/assets` so it's not possible that directory isn't in assets compile path.

My config on `application.rb` and `production.rb`:

```
config.assets.compile = true

# I checked the environment variable, it responds to 'enabled',
# which would return true for the option.
config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

# Which I changed to expire old assets.
config.assets.version='1.1'
```

I tried these, but they didn't work:

- `$ heroku restart`
- `$ heroku run rake assets:precompile`
- `$ heroku run rake assets:clobber`

The weird thing with these is that they do not affect assets in heroku server, which I checked with `$ heroku run ls public/assets`. Even after `$ rake assets:precompile`, even though it says this:

```
WRITING /app/public/assets/application-{VERY_LONG_HASH}.js
WRITING /app/public/assets/application-{VERY_LONG_HASH}.js.gz
WRITING /app/public/assets/application-{VERY_LONG_HASH}.css
WRITING /app/public/assets/application-{VERY_LONG_HASH}.css.gz
```

when I peek with the `$ heroku run ls public/assets`, I still see old assets staying there.

**EDIT:** I solved it by deleting all the local assets in `public/assets`, recompiling them with `$ rake assets:clean && rake assets:precompile` and including these assets in my `git` repository. Here is one concern:

Shouldn't heroku be responsible of compiling my assets on the fly? I think I shouldn't be compiling my assets everytime I deploy my application. Thanks.

Comment: Though you solved it, I think the problem was you were doing all operations like `assets:clobber` and `assets:precompile` inside a `heroku` instance of app instead of doing that in your local instance and pushing to heroku. And about your question, I wonder that too since I have started using heroku (i.e 1 year).

Answer (score 2):

Run on local

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Next `git add .`

Next `got commit -m"assets precompile"`

Next `git push origin yourBranchName`

Deploy on heroku and you are done

Comment: This is a botched solution.... You don't want to add the compiled assets to your git repository.

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit your changes first.
Then execute `git push heroku yourbranch:master`

Comment: I already have github integration with enabled auto deploy. As I stated, I am pretty sure the application has been deployed.

Comment: check the status of our code by git status, if it displays any files, then u need to add & commit them

Comment: What I want to know is, do we need to include our precompiled assets for committing? Isn't that violeting the reason behind compiling assets?

And as I said, I am sure that the problem isn't with the commits or pushes.